# Adding django import_export to Abstract User Model

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Below is my admin.py file.

I want to implement the import_export feature on the Employee model which is Abstract User Model.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from inventory.models import Employee
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
admin.site.unregister(Group)

# admin.site.register(Employee)


class EmployeeAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ('emp_num', 'emp_name', 'email',
                    'emp_designation', 'is_admin', 'is_staff')
    search_fields = ('emp_num', 'emp_name')

    readonly_fields = ('last_login',)
    ordering = ('emp_num',)
    filter_horizontal = ()
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)
    fieldsets = ()


admin.site.register(Employee, EmployeeAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [**`ImportExportModelAdmin`** [readthedocs.io]](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_admin.html#import_export.admin.ImportExportModelAdmin) is just a `ModelAdmin` with a [**`ImportExportMixin`** [readthedocs.io]](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_admin.html#import_export.admin.ImportExportMixin), so probably the most clean solution is use the `ImportExportMixin`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from inventory.models import Employee
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from import_export.admin import ImportExportMixin
admin.site.unregister(Group)

# admin.site.register(Employee)


class EmployeeAdmin(ImportExportMixin, UserAdmin):
    list_display = ('emp_num', 'emp_name', 'email',
                    'emp_designation', 'is_admin', 'is_staff')
    search_fields = ('emp_num', 'emp_name')

    readonly_fields = ('last_login',)
    ordering = ('emp_num',)
    filter_horizontal = ()
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)
    fieldsets = ()


admin.site.register(Employee, EmployeeAdmin)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! I spent hours on this. Also, how can I exclude some fields to be exported like password  ?

Comment: @NIHIRAGARWAL: you can specify a `resource_class` (https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_admin.html#import_export.admin.ImportMixin.resource_class) where you specify what to include/exclude.

Comment: The problem here is that if you added custom fields to your User model, it won't be shown in your admin interface

Comment: @KaissB.: you can define a model admin for the custom user model, and add these to the `list_display`.

Comment: Even with list_display, the mixin just overrides everything. My suggestion is to create a proxy model. Use the proxymodel with the UserAdmin, and the other one with the import export view. I'll put this answer as well.

Comment: @KaissB.: no the `ImportExportModelAdmin` will override everything, that is why the mixin is used: to only override these specific methods: https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/main/import_export/admin.py#L65-L728 It only patches the template name, adds an item to the urls, and handles the rest in a separate page.

Comment: I just tried it and I couldn't find the custom fields I added to my model.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is to create a Proxy Model that will be using the UserAdmin (with all features of hashing passwords and so on).

Here's how to do it:

In your models:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    << my fields >>

class MyProxyModel(MyModel):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

In your admin.py file:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin

from .models import MyModel, MyProxyModel

class MyModelAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    << list_display, search fields, and all custom admin stuff >>

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
admin.site.register(MyProxyModel, UserAdmin)
```

Now, if you want to manage your objects with custom search fields and filters, you use the ModelAdmin, and if you want to use Built In Django features like password hashing, you use the proxy model admin.